# No message inside console with autocomplete script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

this function works fine addSpecificationValue inside my table, my problem is how to make a new row creation an autocompletion called a file to display information come from MySQL. I use the script for that token-input

[http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/][1]

I  developed a specific function to try when I want to create a new row to include in input with autocompletion

It doesn't work and inside the console, there is no message. I suppose the autocompletion is not called or it's problem with token-input.

I don't know how to do that about to include an autocompletion inside the new row with the id `#specificationName" + specification_row`
My skills are limited

Thank you for your help

```
     $products_specification_ajax = OSCOM::link('products_specification_ajax');
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
      var specification_row = $t;

      $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#specificationName" + specification_row).tokenInput("{$products_specification_ajax}",
        {
          tokenLimit: 1,
          resultsLimit: 5,
          onResult: function (results) {
            $.each(results, function (index, value) {
              value.name = value.id + " " + value.name;
            });
            return results;
          }
        });
      });





      function addSpecificationValue() {
       html  = '<tr id="specification-row' + specification_row + '">';

    //specification_name
       html += '<td>';


       html += '  <input type="text" name="products_specification[' + specification_row + '][name]" value="" id="specificationName' + specification_row + '" class="form-control token-input" />';


       html += '</td>';


    //remove    
        html += '  <td class="text-md-right"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#specification-row' + specification_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
        html += '</tr>';

           $('#specification tbody').append(html);

        specification_row++;
    } 
    </script>  
    <br />
    EOD;


  [1]: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/
```

Comment: Does that code block actually work? It appears to be riddled with php syntax issues

Comment: @IsThisJavascript yes it work, I just display the element the most important. The problem is there $(document).ready(function() { to make something correct